# video-js _V_ is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

in a page i have added a video.js html5 player. in a function i am doing this:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
myPlayer.pause();
```

and it works. But when i try to do something like:

```
myPlayer.currentTime(30);
```

it doesn't work. even though this works:

```
alert(myPlayer.currentTime);
```

i don't understand why the play() and pause() functions work and i can get some information about the status of the player, but i cant use any other functions from the video-js API.

i know i should be getting the video item like this:

```
var myPlayer = _V_("example_video_1");
```

but if i do it that way i get: *V* is not defined in the console. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using an older js call to the code, there's a cross over to a newer version. Since you don't state which version you're using it's difficult to analyse. Try replacing:

```
_V_
```

with

```
videojs
```

****Update: Use 'vjs'; if you upgrade or have started using version 4.4.3, it explains in the dev code...**

```
*
* **ALIASES** videojs, _V_ (deprecated)
*
* The `vjs` function can be used to initialize or retrieve a player.
*
```

Comment: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (VideoJS)